# Do Cauchy sequences converge or not?

Tags: real-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKOru.jpg)

In the pages 66 and 67 of the book “Understanding Analysis” (second edition) Stephen Abbott, it is written the following sentence:

“ *To spoil the surprise, we will argue in this section that in fact these two definitions are equivalent: **Convergent sequences are Cauchy sequences, and Cauchy sequences converge.*** ”

Further, in the same page 67:

**Theorem 2.6.4** (Cauchy Criterion). *A sequence converges if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence.*

And then he proves this theorem (without mentioning a word about complete spaces!).

Question: If Cauchy sequences converge only in complete spaces, isn’t it a mistake in the book above to state such a thing without mentioning that this definition is restricted to complete spaces?

I’m studying Functional Analysis and I’m confused, because I strongly learned that Cauchy sequences are convergent.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhpas in this context the book is assuming that the space is complete? Sometimes earlier in a chapter or a section, they add another assumption which they omit restating later on.

Comment: At that point in that book theyr're only talking about sequences of real numbers. (Proof: In the definition of "Cauchy sequence" it says $|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$ instead of $d(a_n,a_m)<\epsilon$.)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the Cauchy criterion is only valid in complete metric spaces. However, Abbott only considers Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb R$ and *proves that they converge*. This means that he *proves that $\mathbb R$ is a complete metric space*, but doesn't explicitly define the abstract concept of a complete metric space.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it depends on the space!

Certainly, if a sequence converges it is Cauchy (regardless). But the converse is only true for certain spaces. I like the way an old professor of mine described it:

> All Cauchy sequences *want* to converge to something, but if it can't it's not the fault of the sequence, it's a fault of the space.

For example, the sequence $\{3,3.1,3.14,3.141,3.1415,\ldots\}$ really 'wants' to converge (it is Cauchy). Certainly, if we consider this a sequence of real numbers, it does converge to $\pi$.

But if we are in the space of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ (using the metric topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$), this sequence does not converge because $\pi$ is not rational. Again, the sequence itself is doing everything it can to converge, but it is the fault of the space $\mathbb{Q}$ for not bothering to supply the necessary point - $\pi$.

So the statement: "A sequence converges if and only if the sequence is Cauchy", is only true in certain spaces. In fact, we give a special name to such spaces where this statement is true, namely *complete spaces*. You can read a tiny bit more about them [at this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space). But of course, this is a big topic. Note that metric spaces have completions. In fact, this is often how you see the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ as a student (unless you take the Dedekind cut approach).

The book is neither right nor wrong without further reading. Because it is 'Undergraduate' Analysis, I assume they are probably implicitly (or explicitly hopefully) working over $\mathbb{R}$ - which is complete. But you are correct that the statement is not generally true for analysis over *all* spaces. I would check the Preface or previous chapters to see if it was mentioned that this restriction was the case. If it was, perhaps a reminder somewhere in that section would have been good.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. It is extremely satisfactory! But I still see it as logically wrong to say: **it is possible that a Cauchy sequence does not converge**. This statement is not true. Actually, *every* Cauchy sequence converges, just not necessarily to a point in the space we are dealing with, but it *always* converges! Is it right?

Comment: If the definition of divergent sequence is a sequence that does not converge, you can not say that *there are Cauchy sequences that do not converge*, because it implies that there are Cauchy sequences that diverge, and it is not true. There are only Cauchy sequences that fail to converge to a point **inside** of some spaces.

Comment: No, it's wrong to say that's not right. If we're given a topological space $X$ and a sequence $a_n$ in $X$ it's meaningless in general to say the sequence converges to something outside $X$; the definition of $a_n\to L$ starts with $L\in X$.

Comment: Remember, we define converge and to say something diverges means that it *does not converge*. There are many ways something can diverge, e.g to go $\pm\infty$, oscillate or just generally 'bounce around', etc. But strictly speaking it means just not converge. As for converge, we say a sequence converges to a point $P$ in your space if the sequence gets 'arbitrarily close' to $P$. But notice in my example you will never find such a $P$ because $\pi \notin \mathbb{Q}$. So the sequence I give diverges.